# How to store and use a 300KB lookup table in a Python app?

Tags: python

I'm currently writing a port scanner and I'd like the program to show a description for each port in the output (e.g.: "http", "ssh", etc). I plan to use the [IANA port list](https://www.iana.org/assignments/service-names-port-numbers), but it would be ~300 kilobytes as a Python dictionary.

What are my options here? Should I just use the giant dict, or compress it in some way, or embed it as a SQLite database? I'd appreciate any and all suggestions as to how I can fit a giant data pack inside a Python program.

(Obviously the easiest solution is to just not use the IANA list, but I would like to at least try it first. Plus, I'm genuinely curious as to how this could be accomplished.)

Comment: I don't think you have a choice. If you want the descriptions you should read them in and store them in a `dict` ready for when you need to show them. Anyway ~300kB is nothing compared to the multi-GB available in main memory for computers today.

Comment: Keep it simple, put it in a .csv file, gzip it, include that with your program.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an excellent module called [klepto](https://klepto.readthedocs.io/en/latest/klepto.html), which helps you to both access the data via cache and an archive for storing the data. It stores the data to a DB but uses interface like a dictionary for your uses.

On a different note, the filesize is small enough that there shouldnt be too much of a performance penalty even if you use normal python dicts and pickle them after transacting.